# How to fix accidentally duplicated data in a BigQuery table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery, with a very large table with a `month` TIMESTAMP field:

```
code STRING
org STRING
month TIMESTAMP
```

I've accidentally written the data for one month twice, by importing it twice and wrongly using append mode when I did.

Given that BigQuery doesn't allow me to update or delete data, what's the best way to get rid of the duplicate data?

I've started by copying all the data except for the problem month to a temporary table:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE month!=TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01')
```

Now what I'd ideally like to do is get *one* copy of the data for `2012-01-01`, removing each duplicate row, into the same temporary table. Is this possible in SQL?

If it isn't, I guess I can just re-import the data for `2012-01-01` directly into the temporary table, but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

Either way, I'll get a clean copy of the data into the temporary table, then re-import it into the permanent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not classic deduping problem, rather fixing accidental data appending.
If this happend just recently (few days, up to 7) I would suggest trying [Snapshot decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot_decorators)
It allows you to references a snapshot of the table at a specific time.
So if you can determin time before you appended data  - this can help.
You still will need select data out of this table (with decorator) and write it to new table

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query with window functions to pick only one entry, like this exampe, and you can write the result to a different table or to the same table.

```
select * from (
SELECT 
rank() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as _rank,
*
FROM [user_profile_event] 
) where _rank=1
```

In this example we pick duplicates by user_id, and we use the latest value that's why we have `timestamp desc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicates by doing :

```
SELECT 
  code
  , org
  , month 
FROM mytable 
WHERE month=TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01')
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been up for awhile, but have you considered a "SELECT DISTINCT" statement? "SELECT DISTINCT" returns only distinct (different) values for your column. http://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct

Comment: I disagree with the reviewer.  This is not a "link-only" answer.  However, you can improve this answer by adding the precise SQL code needed to solve the OP's problem.